# Jquery is not working in Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my show page , I want to add picture upload functionality and also put additional button to add multiple pictures . May be there is some problem in my J Query code correct that also please .

My show page code -

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :avatar,label: 'Upload Photo' , class: 'input_avatar' %>
      </div>
      </div> 

       <% unless params['controller'] == 'accident_records' and params['action'] == 'edit' %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 

            <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="-" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
          </div>
        </div><br>
      <%end%>


       <div class="col-sm-3">
       <label></label>
          <div class="actions">
             <%= f.submit'Creat Accident Record', :class => class_name, data: { disable_with: data_info } %>
            <% if params['controller'] == 'accident_records' and params['action'] == 'edit' %>
           <%end%>
```

Controller Code -

```
def download_jpg
    @accident_record = AccidentRecord.find(params[:id])
    if File.exist?(@accident_record.avatar.path)
    send_file @accident_record.avatar.path,
              filename: @accident_record.avatar_file_name,
              type: @accident_record.avatar_content_type,
              disposition: 'attachment'
              else
    flash[:alert] = "No file found Please contact to Admin!"
    redirect_to accident_records_path
    end
  end
```

J Query -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, 
        newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      
        newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 
        newElem.find('.input_avatar').attr('avatar','accident_record['+ newNum +'][avatar]').attr('id', newNum + '_accident_record_avatar').val('');

    $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

    if (newNum == 5)
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); 
  });

  $('#btnDel').click(function () {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
          {
              var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
              $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                  if (num -1 === 1)
              $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
              $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "+ Additional Accident Images");});
          }
      return false;
  });
  $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
  $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

My Full Show HTML Page -

```
<div class="box box-default">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Accident Record</h3>
      <div class="box-tools pull-right"> </div>
  </div><!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body">
    <%= bootstrap_form_for(@accident_record,html: {id: 'accident_record'}) do |f| %>
  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Accident Code</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.code %></td>

      <th><strong>Employee</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.employee.try(:manual_employee_code) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Department</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.department.try(:name) %></td>

      <th><strong>Root Cause</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.root_cause_master.try(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Accident Date</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.accident_date %></td>

      <th><strong>ESIC No</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.esic_no %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Case Type</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.case_type %></td>

      <th><strong>Type of Injury</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.type_of_injury %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th><strong>Leave Date</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.leave_date_range %></td>

      <th><strong>No of Day</strong></th>
      <td><%= @accident_record.no_of_day %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
      <td colspan="3"><%= @accident_record.description %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_accident_record_path(@accident_record),class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm fa fa-edit' %> |
      <%= link_to 'Back', accident_records_path,class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-arrow-left' %>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="field">
              <%= f.file_field :avatar,label: 'Upload Photo' , class: 'input_avatar' %>
          </div>
      </div> 
  <% unless params['controller'] == 'accident_records' and params['action'] == 'edit' %>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
          <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 
          <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="-" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
      </div>
  </div><br>
  <%end%>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label></label>
          <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit'Creat Accident Record', :class => class_name, data: { disable_with: data_info } %>
              <% if params['controller'] == 'accident_records' and params['action'] == 'edit' %>
              <%end%>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
   <%end%><br>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
                  var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, 
                      newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      
                      newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 
                      newElem.find('.input_avatar').attr('avatar','accident_record['+ newNum +'][avatar]').attr('id', newNum + '_accident_record_avatar').val('');

                  $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
                  $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();

                  $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

                  if (newNum == 5)
                  $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit"); 
                });

                $('#btnDel').click(function () {
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this section? This cannot be undone."))
                        {
                            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
                            $('#entry' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {$(this).remove();
                                if (num -1 === 1)
                            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
                            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "+ Additional Accident Images")});
                        }
                    return false;
                });
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
              });
</script>
```

Comment: Any console error? Also it will be more good if you gave the actual html code of view not the php code structure

Comment: No , it is not showing any error .

Comment: Please check I uploaded full HTML code .

Comment: Actually i am unable to find these elements in your html like:- `.clonedInput` and `#entry`. elements with this classes and id are missing

Comment: <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput"> i mentioned this line after bootstrap_form , but now it is repeating the whole form . I only want avatar field .

Comment: do you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` installed ? try adding this on top of your show page `<%= javascript_include_tag "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js" %>`